# How to get the results (succeeded or failed) of previous stages/jobs in a pipeline of GitLab CI?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

In one pipeline there are multiple stages. How can I get the results (succeeded or failed) of previous stages/jobs in the last stage/job of a pipeline?

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use the gitlab-ci job api to find the status from its response;
However, depending on your use case; you can also use `CI_JOB_STATUS` in the 'after_script` of the same job.

You can use a custom variable as a flag, that you can set in the after script of the same job based on `CI_JOB_STATUS`.

Note: `CI_JOB_STATUS` can be `success`, `failed`, or `canceled`

Comment: `CI_JOB_STATUS` is the value of the current job but not the previous jobs

Answer (score 2):

You can use "`artifacts:reports:dotenv`" feature

Check out below code:

```
---
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - VAR1=foo
    - VAR2=bar
    - echo VAR1="${VAR1}" > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/variables.env
    - echo VAR2="${VAR2}" >> $CI_PROJECT_DIR/variables.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: variables.env

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo VAR1 is $VAR1
    - echo VAR2 is $VAR2
```

This was a famous ask from many people to GitLab, check out [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22638), above code is taken from this discussion only.

Comment: Link to git-lab documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job